# Problem with reading the values of variables in constraint programming (CP)

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, opl

I am trying to access the variables of my optimization problem solved with constraint programming (CP) in Cplex Opl IDE. In the previous versions of Cplex, I used to reach the variable values through the "problem browser" module. But now, I can't reach the variables' values since that part is empty despite getting a feasible solution. And in the outline menu, the variables are just listed, and the explanation of each variable is written faintly similar to the inactive objects. I am using OPL 22.1.1.0 Model. What is the problem?[image: this the screenshot of the inactive variables]

Comment: Hi, can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: @alex I added the screenshot to the question box. Thank you in advance for your support. looking forward ton hearing from you soon

Comment: I am facing the same problem in version 12.10 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to show the problem browser ?
I am afraid you mixed the problem browser and the outline

[image: Show problem browser]

Comment: Sure, the problem browser actually exists on the right side of the screenshot which is empty.